# Scrolling Safari page with Ctrl+N and Ctrl+P

Tags: keyboard, safari, shortcut, macos

I used to be able to scroll the page in Safari using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> shortcuts. I've recently noticed that these shortcuts no longer work. Does this feature no longer exist, or could it somehow be enabled?

Comment: Ctrl n & p work on Mojave, not on Ventura. Can't test anything in between.

Comment: Essential documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/cpsh003/mac